# FSharpCore 4.4.0.0 for version fsharp 4.0 vs fsharpcore 4.1 with fsharp 4.1

Tags: f#

I'm confused.

I'm upgrading an old project that has references to FSharp.Core 4.4 everywhere yet the latest version of fsharp.core on nuget is `4.1.*.*`

Is there a document explain what is going on with the version numbers going backwards?

Comment: They aren't. You are confusing package numbers with assembly version numbers.

Comment: There is no FSharp.Core 4.4 package. The *assemblies* inside the latest package (4.1.12) have an assembly version of 4.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document is [here](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html), under "FSharp.Core version numbers"

FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0 corresponds to F# 4.0 running on .NET 4.5+.

The Nuget packages have a different versioning system where the first two digits are the F# version. Each nuget package targets one version of F#, but contains multiple FSharp.Core versions for different profiles. E.g. FSharp.Core Nuget version 4.1.12 is the latest Nuget package for F# 4.1 and contains FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0 for desktop, and various FSharp.Core portable profiles 3.N.4.1.